# How to pass a string to a function, which can create a binary later?

Tags: erlang

This is my function, when I call my_conv("2312144", 10, 10), it gives me "bad argument" error

```
my_conv(S, Start, End) ->
  Res = <<Start:8, End:8, S:1024>>.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A string cannot be used inside a binary expression without conversion. You need to convert the string to a binary by using `list_to_binary(S)`.

I would recommend the following expression:

```
my_conv(S, Start, End) ->
    list_to_binary(<<Start:8, End:8>>, S]).
```

(Note here that `list_to_binary/1` actually accepts a deep IO list and not just a pure string).

If you intend to pad your binary to 1024 bytes (or 1040 including your newlines) you can do so afterwards:

```
my_conv(S, Start, End) ->
    pad(1040, list_to_binary(<<Start:8, End:8>>, S])).

pad(Width, Binary) ->
    case Width = byte_size(Binary) of
        N when N =< 0 -> Binary;
        N -> <<Binary/binary, 0:(N*8)>>
    end.
```

Comment: thanks! could you tell me what does <<Binary/binary, 0:(N*8)>> mean ?

Comment: <<0:(N*8)>> is a 0 with the width of N*8 bits = N bytes.